# Can't make requests to Flask API server on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

**Problem**

I have a Flask API server running on AWS EC2. Requests executed on the server work fine:

`curl 'http://localhost:5000/foods`

But when I make the same request to the public DNS (or public IP) from my local machine `curl 'http://ec2-3-35-218-9.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/foods`...

I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-3-35-218-9.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 5000 after 39 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

**Info**

1. Inbound rules are configured to accept all traffic from ports 80, 443, and 5000.
2. The VPC Subnet accepts all inbound traffic from all ports.
3. I ran a test by spinning up another EC2 on the same subnet and tried to `ping` the API server, but it came back with `request timeout`.
4. Asked ChatGPT and it seems similarly stumped...